# Automating ACF Plots in R for many Time Series in one Data Frame

Tags: r, time-series

I am attempting to automate plotting of many ACFs for different time series so I can quickly detect if these TS can be well modeled by an ARMA process. I have created the following loop with the intention of printing out each plot to its own jpeg.

I have already tested the loop when replacing line 3, D=acf(data.ts) with the decompose function, and was able to return all of those results. Moreover, out of the loop, if I replace the variable i with any TS from the data frame, I can view the jpeg inside RStudio, but I don't want to spend the time to right_click -> Save_as everything.

I get the following error when I run my code:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Here is the loop I have been working off of.

```
for (i in 2:272){
  data.ts=ts(df1[i,], start=c(2011,1), end = c(2016,12),fr=12)
  mypath = file.path("S:", "Work")
  jpeg(paste("acfplot_", i, ".jpeg", sep=""))
  acf(data.ts, lag.max = 999)
  dev.off()
}
```

Edit: The solution involves adding a ylimit to the ACF function as seen below in @alex-braksator reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a ylim to your acf call to specify the y-limit bounds when R plots it.

Normally, your ACF plots will show blue dotted lines that represent 95% confidence bounds. That is what I'm assuming is what you're using to determine significant lags and whether or not your TS can be modeled. Those blue lines are calculated with:
`qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(length(data.ts))`

So in your case, make that the ylim bound of your plotting window, maybe plus 1 or 2

`ylimit <- qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(length(data.ts)) + 1
acf(data.ts, lag.max = 999, ylim=c(-ylimit, ylimit))`

Hope this helps. Let me know if you still get errors.